# how to gridview with option value with corresponding id from database

Tags: php, javascript, yii

in my  YII form i have a dropdown depending on a table to another table which saves the id of the depended table like below

```
<div class="column">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'employee'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'employee',CHtml::listData(Employee::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('status'=>'Active')),'emp_id','emp_name'),array('empty'=>'select')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'employee'); ?>
</div>
```

from above the form will save emp_id of the emp_name.in grid view also it showing same id only.but i just need to display emp_name of corresponding emp_id and should saved as id in database.anyone have  idea post i am new to this thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your grid view

```
'columns'=>array(
              ....
//    'employee',
       array(
            'name'  => 'employee',
            'value' => 'Employee::model()->findByPk($data->employee)->emp_name',
            ),
```

And if relation to Employee model is defined in your model then you can use

```
'value'=>'$data->relation_name->emp_name'
```

Comment: for list view shall i use like th

Comment: HI Rajat singhal i need another help.same problem to solve in detail view can you help in this  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data'=>$model,
 'attributes'=>array(employee),
)); ?> problem in the above code i tried as like gridview but it doesnt work